# Autoscaling Google cloud kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, openfaas

We have an app running under a Google Cloud Kubernetes cluster, things are running fine in my testing scenario. We went to set up autoscaling for these pods - we'll probably never need to go to 0, but want it to scale up to (for now) 20 pods, and back down, obviously. We are deploying using faas-cli. First, tried:

```
faas-cli deploy --replace --update=false -f ./process-listing-image.yml \
    --gateway=https://openfaas.ihouseprd.com \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.min=1" \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.max=20" \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.factor=5"
```

But that gave us 1 pod, and never moved. The it was suggested to use:

```
faas-cli deploy --replace --update=false -f ./process-listing-image.yml \
    --gateway=https://openfaas.ihouseprd.com \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.min=0" \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.max=20" \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.factor=5"
```

But that still gave us but one pod. I most recently tried:

```
faas-cli deploy --replace --update=false -f ./process-listing-image.yml \
    --gateway=https://openfaas.ihouseprd.com \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.min=5" \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.max=20" \
    --label "com.openfaas.scale.factor=5"
```

Which produced 5 pods, but it hasn't scaled past that, despite there being thousands of requests waiting. Looking at the Cloud Console "Deployment Details" screen, I see the five pods, but can't tell if all 5 are working.

Any idea why these things aren't scaling?

Comment: Hello, while I'm trying to reproduce your issue can you tell me what version are you running of kubernetes? is it GKE or you deployed manually using kubeadm in Compute Engine? also, share the pod deployment resources requirement and how are you running the tests for load?